# Control fan speed under linux without nvidia drivers

Tags: linux, qemu, linux-kvm, nvidia-graphics-card, speedfan

I have quemu-kvm configuration like this - IGP on host (linux) and Nvidia on guest (windows). I blacklist nvidia drivers under linux (arch dist.).

Is there a way to set GPU fan speed under linux (it's very noisy) before I run windows (on windows fan working quietly).

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

kernel 3.16.0-1-mainline

GPU: gigabyte GeForce GTX 660

```
$sudo lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 5000
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
        Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
        Kernel driver in use: hsw_uncore

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 42
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
        I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
        Memory behind bridge: f6000000-f70fffff
        Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000e0000000-00000000e9ffffff
        Capabilities: [88] Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 5000
        Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [a0] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
        Capabilities: [140] Root Complex Link
        Capabilities: [d94] #19
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
        Kernel modules: shpchp

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device d000
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 49
        Memory at f7400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
        Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
        I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
        Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
        Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
        Kernel driver in use: i915
        Kernel modules: i915

00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2010
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 50
        Memory at f7834000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Controller (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 5007
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
        Memory at f7820000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
        Kernel modules: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family ME Interface #1
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 1c3a
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
        Memory at f783d000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Kernel driver in use: mei_me
        Kernel modules: mei_me

00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-V
        DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device e000
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48
        Memory at f7800000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
        Memory at f783c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        I/O ports at f080 [size=32]
        Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [e0] PCI Advanced Features
        Kernel driver in use: e1000e
        Kernel modules: e1000e

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI Controller #2 (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 5006
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
        Memory at f783b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
        Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
        Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
        Kernel modules: ehci_pci

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family HD Audio Controller
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device a182
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 51
        Memory at f7830000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev d0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
        Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot-), MSI 00
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 5001
        Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
        Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev d0) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
        Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
        Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 5001
        Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
        Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI Controller #1 (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 5006
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
        Memory at f783a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
        Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
        Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
        Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
        Kernel modules: ehci_pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family H97 Controller
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 5001
        Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
        Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device b005
        Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
        I/O ports at f0d0 [size=8]
        I/O ports at f0c0 [size=4]
        I/O ports at f0b0 [size=8]
        I/O ports at f0a0 [size=4]
        I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
        Memory at f7839000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
        Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
        Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
        Kernel driver in use: ahci
        Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 9 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 5001
        Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 11
        Memory at f7838000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=256]
        I/O ports at f040 [size=32]

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK106 [GeForce GTX 660] (rev a1) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 354e
        Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 11
        Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16M]
        Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [disabled] [size=128M]
        Memory at e8000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [disabled] [size=32M]
        I/O ports at e000 [disabled] [size=128]
        Expansion ROM at f7000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
        Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [b4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
        Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
        Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
        Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
        Capabilities: [900] #19
        Kernel modules: nouveau

01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK106 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
        Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 354e
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
        Memory at f7080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
        Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

03:00.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev 41) (prog-if 01 [Subtractive decode])
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
        Bus: primary=03, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=32
        Capabilities: [90] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [a0] Subsystem: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd Device 8892
```

Comment: Which release number of Arch Linux? On what make and model of PC? Are you trying to alter the speed of the CPU fan, the graphics card fan, the power supply fan, and/or other fans? If the graphic card fan, please also advise its make and model. Click on the grey 'edit' link above and to the left and add that information to the original post, please.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, setting the GPU fan speed of a nvidia graphics card under Linux is possible, see this [related question on askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42494/how-can-i-change-the-nvidia-gpu-fan-speed). In short:

- Edit your `xorg.conf` and add `Option "Coolbits" "4"` to `Section "Screen"`. Or just execute `nvidia-xconfig --cool-bits=4` which will generate you a completely new `xorg.conf` and sets this option for you. This enables fan control settings.
- After restarting X or your computer run `nvidia-settings`. You will find a new GPU fan setting located under *Thermal Settings*. You can also control it via command-line by first enabling this setting via `nvidia-settings -a "[gpu:0]/GPUFanControlState=1"` and then enforcing a specific fan speed via `nvidia-settings -a "[fan:0]/GPUTargetFanSpeed=65"` (in this case 65%).